Is there any evidence the scene with Noir in S04E06 of "The Boys" was inspired by Shrek?
Just watched S04E07 of "The Boys". Without too many spoilers there is a scene where:

 we hear Noir talk and Starlight says, "You can talk."  Later we see Noir flying and Butcher saying, "You can fly".  Warning, language Noir Fight scene Flying and Talking

Is there any evidence to suggest this scene was contained an inside joke/reference/homage to the scene in Shrek when:

  We see Donkey talking and flying and people saying, "He can fly."  and "He can talk."   Donkey Flying & Talking

The order of 'surprise events' is slightly different.  But it does seem like the kind of parody that "The Boys" has done before.
